# Continuous function of $R_0$-space into non-$R_0$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function of an $R_0$-space into a topological space (non-necessary $R_0$-space) (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom#Main_definitions) to recall what an $R_0$-space is).

I wish to find out the conditions to ensure that if $X$ is $R_0$ then $f(X)$ also is.

For the momment, I have found that if $f$ is open and injective then $f(X)$ is $R_0$. Moreover, I know that if $f$ is not open or is not injective, then $f(X)$ may be no $R_0$:

- For if $f$ is not open, given two separated points $x,y\in X$ and two (open) neighbourhoods $V_x$ and $V_y$ such that $y\notin V_x$ and $x\notin V_y$, then $f(y)\notin f(V_x)$ and $f(x)\notin f(V_y)$, but $f(V_x)$ and $f(V_y)$ needn't to be neigbhbourhoods of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ resp. An example illustrating that is the identity map of $\{0,1\}$ (discrete) onto $\{0,1\}$ (Sierpinski space).
- Similarly, if $f$ is open but not injective, despite that $f(V_x)$ and $f(V_y)$ are neighbourhoods of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ and that $y\notin V_x$ and $x\notin V_y$, it is poosible that $f(x)\in f(V_y)$ and that $f(y)\in f(V_x)$ (for example if $f(x)=f(y)$).

However, I can't find an example illustrating the second case. My problem is that I can't find continuous open functions of an $R_0$-space into a non-$R_0$-space. My first try was to consider a map from the Sorgrenfey line onto the Sierpinski space (because it is disconnected) but that map was not open. Then I considered the identity from $[-1,1]$ with the usual subspace topology onto $[-1,1]$ endowed with the overlapping interval topology, but it was open neither.

Can you provide an example for the second case, please?

EDIT: The result is trivial if $f$ is constant. I'm interested when $f$ is non-constant, i.e. $f(X)$ has at least two points, so in the above, asuume that $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: I'm fairly sure neither of your conditions is necessary: Take $X$ to be the disjoint union of an $R_0$ space $A$ with a space $B$ that is not $R_0$, with the obvious topology. This is not $R_0$ because of the $B$ part. Take $f$ to be open and injective (and whatever other conditions are needed to ensure that $f(B)$ is $R_0$) on $B$, and neither open nor injective on $A$. Then $f$ is neither open nor injective, but $f(X) = f(A)\cup f(B)$ is $R_0$, since $A$ is $R_0$ and $f|_B$ is open and injective. 

More explictly, the constant map is neither open nor injective, but $f(X)$ is $R_0$.

Comment: I can't follows your reasoning. If $B$ is not $R_0$, I can't imagine how $f(B)$ (that for you is homeomorphict to $B$) can be $R_0$. On the other hand, if $f$ is neither open nor injective, then $f(A)$ needn't to be $R_0$ (see my example). Regarding your final sentence, I'l edit your question to exclude a single-point spaces.

Comment: @Dog_69 The statement "i'm interested in spaces with at least two points" is unrelated to "$f$ being constant is trivial". Unless you additionally assume that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: Also, consider $f:X\to Y$ continuous, surjective, non-open, non-injective with both $X,Y$ being $R_0$, e.g. the double wrapping map $[0,2)\to S^1$. These conditions are clearly not necessary.

Comment: @Dog_69 It's nothing to do with 1-point spaces. Take any $R_0$ space $X$ with more than one point and any space $Y$. Choose some $y_0 \in Y$. Then $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(x) = y_0$ for all $x$ has $f(X) = \{y_0\}$ is both trivial and discrete, so is $R_0$, but $f$ is neither open nor injective. You being able to find one map that is not open/injective but does not have your property does not mean that all non-open/injective maps do not have your property.

Comment: @frakish The stetament ''spaces with more than one point'' refers to $f(X)$. It's obvious that if $f$ is constant $f(X)$ is $R_0$. For your other remark, your are assuming that $Y$ is $R_0$, which may not happen.

Comment: @user3482749: I have edited the question. See now.

Comment: A couple of days ago I edited the question. Now I think that I have found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a simple example:

Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology and $Y=\{0,1\}$ be the Sierpinski space (with $\{1\}$ open). Consider $f:X\rightarrow Y$ defined as $f(0)=0$ and $1$ otherwise. Then:

- $f$ is continuous because $f^{-1}(\{1\})=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$ is open and $f^{-1}(\{0,1\})=\mathbb R$ is also open.
- $f$ is open because $f((a,b))=\{1\}$ if $0\notin (a,b)$ and $\{0,1\}$ if $0\in(a,b)$; in both cases they are open.
- The Sierpinski space is not symmetric because $0$ and $1$ are topologically distinguishable but $1$ belongs to each neighbourhood of $0$.